# Retaining Grid Row selection in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI grid without pagination. I have set the below code to load the data in the grid view while scrolling
          scrollable: { virtual: true },

My problem is, I have selected 100th row in the grid by scrolling . I am refreshing the grid. After refresh, I need to select the 100th row again. Is it possible ?

Regards
Senthil

Answer (score 0):

After refresh select the row you need as shown below

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.select("tr:eq(100)");
```

For more info check out kendo DOC http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select

Answer (score 0):

Basically the question is annotate the row that you have selected when it changes to do so and then in `dataBound` event select that same row.

In order to save the selected row you can do:

```
change: function (e) {
    // Save some information from the selected row
    var item = this.dataItem(this.select());
    // Here we save uid
    var uid = item.uid;
    this.selectedRow = uid;
},
dataBound: function (e) {
    // If we have any row selected
    if (this.selectedRow) {
        // Use this.select for selecting it
        this.select("tr[data-uid='" + this.selectedRow + "']");
    }
}
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/eLk7zkzs/